# some image not load from firebase due to different byte size in android

Tags: android, image, firebase, picasso

I have a firebase database in which multiple urls of images are stored all images have different byte size , but picasso not load all images , just some images loads. i am saving all images after crop, how can i fix issue?

```
                Picasso.get()
                    .load(user_pic)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE) // for offline
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile_image)
                    .error(R.drawable.default_profile_image)
                    .into(dpImage);

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:maxWidth="170dp"
        android:maxHeight="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_profile_image"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:civ_border_width="0.5dp"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging in Picasso to see what is happening.

You can find more info here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-cache-indicators-logging-stats

Anyways, from my personal experience, I recommend switch to Glide:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

```
//Setting it to (6MB)..change it as per requirement
long cacheSize =  1024 * 1024 * 6;

Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                              .memoryCache(new LruCache(cacheSize))
                              .build();
```

You can try increasing the cache size of `picasso` if it still not work use `Glide` it can handle different formats of images better.

Comment: May be your images are of different format try using glide its quite easy to use.  https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: I have tried with glide but not working and all images have same format